# Downloading from an ftp using Python

Tags: python, ftp, download, ftplib

I have a piece of code in Python to download files from an ftp. The code downloads the very first file in the list of *available days* but fails to download the second. What could be the problem?

```
import os, ftplib 
destdir='D:\precipitation\dl' 
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.itc.nl')  
ftp.login('anonymous', '') 
ftp.cwd('pub/mpe/msg') 
available_days=['summsgmpe_20100101.zip','summsgmpe_20100102.zip', 'summsgmpe_20100103.zip', 'summsgmpe_20100104.zip', 'summsgmpe_20100105.zip', 'summsgmpe_20100106.zip', 'summsgmpe_20100107.zip', 'summsgmpe_20100108.zip'] 
hdfs = list() 
for day in available_days : 
    file = available_days[available_days.index(day)] 
    print 'file=', file 
    local_file = os.path.join(destdir, file) 
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %file, open(local_file, 'wb').write) 
    hdfs.append(os.path.abspath(local_file)) 
    ftp.cwd('..')  
ftp.quit()
```

Comment: How does it fail? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: As an aside, the line `file = available_days[available_days.index(day)]` could be replaced with `file = day`. Better yet, just use `for file in available_days:` and drop the following line altogether.

Comment: ftplib.error_perm: 550 The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your call to `ftp.cwd(..)`

That's moving up a directory for each iteration of the list, instead of staying in the correct folder where the files are.